# Modifying list and sending it to front end sends original list

Tags: jsf-2

I couldn't phrase my Title better, but what's happening is: I fetch a list when the page opens, but it should remove one member of it based on something the user does on the page.

I'm using a ui:repeat in the front-end, and the getter method of this list is:

```
public List<Employee> getAvailableLoaders() {
    if (availableLoaderList != null) {
        List<Employee> availableLoaderListWithoutDriver = new ArrayList(availableLoaderList);
        if (selectedDriver != null) {
            logInfo("SelectedDriver is: " + selectedDriver.getName());
            logInfo("List's size before removal is: " + availableLoaderListWithoutDriver.size());
            logInfo("Removal was successfull? " + availableLoaderListWithoutDriver.remove(selectedDriver));
            logInfo("List's size after removal is: " + availableLoaderListWithoutDriver.size());
        }
        return availableLoaderListWithoutDriver;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And my logs say:

```
Info:   SelectedDriver is: [Driver name]
Info:   List's size before removal is: 5
Info:   Removal was successful? true
Info:   List's size after removal is: 4
```

But it still shows a list with the driver removed and 5 members anyway. I know the getter is being called with the correct info and when the place that shows it is called because I'm watching the logs.

Any explanation or suggestion on how should I do this or am I just doing a really stupid mistake?

Comment: Can you add the xhtml template, please?

Comment: @OndřejXichtSvětlík: Better to ask for a [mcve]. Asking for something like 'the xhtml template' often produces way too much or too little... And yes it sometimes might be that the cause is visible with what is posted on request, but it is better that the relevance of an [mcve]  is made clear

Comment: I ended up finding out, it was because I was not updating the place where it was being displayed! But thanks guys! :D

Comment: I guess, you are facing a problem with Bean-scopes: Please add your complete Bean-Code. Ps.: You are also "processing" information in the getter... That's somewhat bad, cause a getter should only return values stored in some private property, not impacting the result of a "bean-property-access".